# Docker run multiple Script always run first one

Tags: docker

I am trying to run two scripts to build Docker

```
RUN /usr/local/src/build.sh
RUN /usr/local/src/install.sh
```

Whenever I am building docker with `docker build` it always runs both scripts though I made changes only in `install.sh` file. I knew Docker Run one after another. the `build.sh` took atleast 1 hour. So that I can save my hours if docker starts from `install.sh` if changes happen.

Thanks

Comment: There are pretty basic [rules for when the build cache is used](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache).  Can you `RUN build.sh` before you `COPY` in files that may or may not have changed?

Comment: Aha!...save my hours...Answer it...I will tick mark asap